# JavaScript Promise: single callback for fulfillment or rejection

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

Is there a native way to define a single callback that gets called *always* regardless of fulfillment or rejection?

**This is what I have:**

```
myPromise.then(
    function(value) { // fulfillment
        alwaysDoThis();
    },
    function(reason) { // rejection
        alwaysDoThis();
    }
);
```

**This is what I want:**

```
myPromise.then(
    function(value) { // fulfillment or rejection
        alwaysDoThis();
    }
);
```

The latter will throw an exception in the case of a rejection, so I know it doesn't do what I want.

Comment: Depends on the promise library. The one shipped by default with ES6 can't do that. Bluebird can.

Comment: Just write one function you can reference by name, then pass into both.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid a library. Though using one is not an impossibility.

Comment: I certainly could write a function to do it. But I was more interested to discover whether something native already exists that I can use. I couldn't find anything in the docs, but I didn't want to assume that the absence of the feature due to the absence of the documentation.

Comment: @Zach Is `.finally()` natively available? Can you link to reference?

Comment: I deleted my comment aboout `.finally(callback);` while I looked this up... http://www.2ality.com/2014/10/es6-promises-api.html I'm going to try this to see if it's builtin.  I don't see it on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise so I'm not too hopeful.

Comment: @Zach Yeah, I couldn't find docs for it on MDN or anywhere else. It appears that when that 2ality article was written it was a proposal. It must not have made it into the final spec for es2015. Babel won't even transpile it with the `stage0` preset.

Comment: I'm looking at this implementation as well... https://gist.github.com/jish/e9bcd75e391a2b21206b

Comment: `Promise.prototype.finally = function(onResolveOrReject) {
      return this.catch(function(reason){
        return reason;
      }).then(onResolveOrReject);
    };`

I found this code here:
https://gist.github.com/jish/e9bcd75e391a2b21206b


Here's a working plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/3da7EINsQLtQjjCLQDYb?p=preview